# How to get custom line item's custom attribute's value after order complete

Tags: 7, commerce

Using [this guide](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/cart) I added a custom line item type to my Drupal Commerce installation and have allowed the customer to add extra data when purchasing an item. When the order is complete I need to get hold of that extra data and use it to build some database rows that will grant them access to the service they have just purchased. I have implemented **hook_commerce_checkout_complete($order)** but I haven't been able to find the data within $order. I know it is there somewhere because I can view the order on the customer's account and have modified the View to show the data next to Unit price, Quantity and Total columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `entity_metadata_wrapper` on `commerce_order`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_checkout_complete
 */
function package_designer_commerce_checkout_complete($order) {

  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item_wrapper) {
    if(isset($line_item_wrapper->field_package_configuration)){
      $package_configuration = $line_item_wrapper->field_package_configuration->value();  
      // You can also get the raw value like this:  
      // $package_configuration = $line_item_wrapper->field_package_configuration->raw();    
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have so far, but I'm new to Drupal and expect to be corrected. The extra field I added to my custom line item is called *package_configuration*

```
function package_designer_commerce_checkout_complete($order) {
    $ow = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);


    foreach ($ow->commerce_line_items as $line_item) {
        $lineItemId = $line_item->line_item_id->value();

        $result = db_query("select * from field_data_field_package_configuration where entity_id = $lineItemId");

        foreach($result as $record){
            $customValue = $record->field_package_configuration_value;  
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You can probably just use `$line_item->field_package_configuration->value()` without the `db_query`